# AmCharts value axis not working

Tags: amcharts

I've got a super-simple column chart with just two columns of data. The dataProvider looks like this:

```
chart.dataProvider = [{
    label: 'some label',
    value: 5000,
}, {
    label: 'some other label',
    value: 7500,
}];
```

I'm setting the value axis to the value, like this:

```
graph.valueField = 'value';
```

The chart is being rendered and the tooltip/balloon thing shows the correct value when you hover over each column, but all of the values on the value axis are shown as 0,000

When I inspect the SVG for the value axis in dev tools, I can see the correct values there in the tspan elements, but it still displays as 0,000 on screen?

Comment: why don't you provide JSFiddle link to your problem

Comment: I did try to recreate the issue on JSFiddle, but I couldn't link to a CDN hosted version which is the same version of AMCharts I am using. I couldn't recreate the issue using the later versions of AMCharts which I could find on CDN, so I wonder if I'm using a buggy version. I will try with an updated version on Monday